# C# extracting character from screenshot image

Tags: c#, character, screenshot, extract

I'm looking for some hints how to manage to get single character (in this case number) from screenshot (from flash game). I've tried almost all most popular commercial/non-commercial software but none of them can handle with a single character. I've been trying Office Document Imaging, LeadTools, Tesseract-OCR, Aspose.OCR. I enclosed the image, a screenshot from the game with given number:

[image]

For me it was obvious that OCR will work but I've been surprised, OCR can't handle with this.
Well you think it's impossible to use OCR to extract this number? Maybe you know some solution for my problem?

Another option is to use image comparing method but this is too slow, I'd prefer not use it.

Comment: You could use an algorithm called cross correlation. For this you would need to have reference images for each number and using cross correlation you can compare them with the number on the screen. Using FFT this is quite fast.

Comment: I had done something similar using AForge.NET. The game is Blackjack so it's comparing every possible number in game there is (12 possibilities for dealer) and then (18 for player) so in every move it's doing 30 comparisons (every comparison take about 1 sec.). So it take a lot of time. To play one hand it take almost 30 sec. It's too much time.. I think your idea is similar to the AForge.Net example I gave you. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe captcha will give you some additional ideas. Perhaps you can google through questions that "break it". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft OneNote automatically parses all characters in images stored in it. Just paste in an image (or use Windows-S to fire up OneNotes screen grab).
Just right click and use Get Text from Picture.

Although it thinks your image contains

‚3

Comment: Please explain how this helps the OP. Is he supposed to use OneNote from inside his application?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't working too. It can't recognize numbers from the sreenshot. For me it's ridiculous that any OCR program can't do that, the number is clear on the image but there is no software that can manage to get a numbers from image...